# I want to add an object to ArrayList but having issue doing it.

Tags: java

```
/**
     *  Add Lambert Conformal CRS to variables
     *  
     * @param field
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
*/

public CoverageField getCRS(CoverageField field) throws Exception {
  log.debug("No problem returning crsField");
  List<TemporalCube> tc = field.getTimeCube();
  CoverageDimensions cd = field.getDimensions();
  CoverageField crsField = new CoverageField(tc,cd);
  crsField.setName("LambertConformal_Projection");
  crsField.setStandardName("Lambert Conformal Projection");
  crsField.setUnits("");
  crsField.setPaddingValue(0);
  return crsField;
}
```

Getting an error "Problem formatting coverage" after I added the above code to my existing  project. Don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: What kind of error you are getting? An exception? And in what line?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace? The posted snippet is not enough.

Comment: Also you need to show us the full code of `TemporalCube`, `CoverageDimensions`, `CoverageField` etc.

Comment: What u are trying to achieve??

Answer (score 0):

you r just passing the list object to the CoverageField() constructor..Check it once in the constructor that you declared..